# How can I send a tweet without taking my hands off the keyboard?

Tags: macos, twitter, notifications

If I'm typing a tweet in Mountain Lion's new Notification Center panel, is there a way to send the tweet without moving my hands to the trackpad to click the "send" button? I've tried <kbd>return</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>, and other key combinations, but nothing obvious sends the message.

[image]

Comment: In the process of trying to find an answer to this question I accidentally found a way to break the "Click to Tweet" button. I typed something in the tweet composer and then hit Esc, then the OS seemed to hang for a minute before closing Notification Center. Now I can click on the "Click to Tweet" button and it registers the click but the composer doesn't open. So, caution: don't try that combo if you care about tweeting.

Comment: I've managed to do that several times tonight. In Terminal, you can reset Notification Center with a `killall NotificationCenter; open /System/Library/CoreServices/Notification\ Center.app/
 `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't intend for this to become a self-answered question, but I think I found the answer:

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

The send mail shortcut works to send a Tweet also. Yay for discoverability.

Comment: The mean thing is that even if you change this combination for Mail.app I haven't found a way to change it for the tweet sheet. (Opened a question.)

Comment: Good observation, @GhostLyrics

Comment: Is there a shortcut for the "Click to Tweet" button itself?

Comment: @RobertoAloi See [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58054/9388) — not a single key, but it can be scripted (and thus assigned a keyboard shortcut)

Comment: You can do the whole process, from opening Notification Centre to sending the tweet, without taking your hands off the keyboard: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/86520/26500