# Is there a way to tweet from a keyboard command?

Tags: macos, keyboard, twitter

I use `CMD space` a million times a day to find files, launch apps, etc.

Wouldn't it be cool if I could press a keyboard combination and get a box to send a tweet?  I know I can do it through notification center but I'm looking for a method that doesn't require me to leave the keyboard.

Comment: You might be able to use the answers to this per question along with [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to tweet. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57668/what-hooks-exist-into-notification-center-twitter-so-that-i-can-tweet-programm

Comment: Perhaps you can try a widget such as [Twidget](http://gettwidget.com/) ?

Answer (score 3):

The official Twitter app lets you define a shortcut in its settings (Global new tweet):
[image]

As far as native Twitter integration goes, I really don't know :)

Comment: That's definitely a step in the right direction.  But unfortunately, I have to have the Twitter app running.  But that's not a huge deal.  Unless someone can come up with a way to do exactly that without the app running, then I will give you the answer shortly.

Comment: How about using a shortcut to run an AppleScript?

Comment: @Moshe in my best Homer Simpson voice:  "Explain how!"

Comment: Although I am not 100% sure I believe Alfred may be able to tackle this somehow, would probably require the power pack though.

Comment: The PowerPack can enable the use of shortcuts to run applescripts, but the trouble is having this script in the first place.

Comment: OMG I just installed alfred.  How could I have NOT known about this??  I will experiment and see if I can get something up.  I am a programmer by trade, after all.  lol

Answer (score 1):

You can send tweets using the Twitter libraries for [Ruby](http://twitter.rubyforge.org) or [Python](http://tweepy.github.com), but it requires signing up at [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -KU -rubygems

require 'twitter'

Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = ""
  config.consumer_secret = ""
  config.oauth_token = ""
  config.oauth_token_secret = ""
end

tweet = `osascript -e 'try
tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
display dialog "" default answer ""
text returned of result
end
end'`.chomp

exit if tweet.empty?
Twitter.update(tweet)
```

[AlfredTweet](http://jdfwarrior.tumblr.com/post/12598255041/alfredtweet) is a Twitter client written as an Alfred extension.

[image]