# Any shortkey for new tweet?

Tags: macos, keyboard, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to tweet from a keyboard command?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58204/is-there-a-way-to-tweet-from-a-keyboard-command)

I want to know, is there any shortcut for creating new tweet in OS X Mountain Lion? If not, how can I define that?

Comment: Add a comment if you really want to tweet from Lion. You'll want to edit this to explain exactly how that will work since Lion does not have notification center or a tweeting UI.

Comment: Sorry, edited. I'm in Mountain Lion.

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate because I'm in Mountain Lion and I mean native twitter client!

Comment: OK - let's link to the native client and this might not be a total duplicate with those changes. You see that there's an answer how to do that already if you use this twitter client - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58205/5472 You will want to explain how your question differs from the linked question for it to get reopen votes.